# Marshal.PtrToStructure Throws ExecutionEngineException in mscorlib.dll

Tags: c#, vb.net, pinvoke

I am trying to get all the computer names of all the pcs on our network using code provided by [Sacha Barber](http://www.codeproject.com/script/Membership/View.aspx?mid=569009). The link to the original article is [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16113/Retreiving-a-list-of-network-computer-names-using). The code was originally in C# but I have converted it to VB. When I run the program in debug mode from Visual Studio it usually (not all the time) runs fine, but when I deploy the program, it almost never runs.

It fails at the following line:

```
Dim svrInfo As _SERVER_INFO_100 = DirectCast(Marshal.PtrToStructure(tmpBuffer, _
                                  GetType(_SERVER_INFO_100)), _SERVER_INFO_100)
```

I get the following error:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.ExecutionEngineException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
HResult=-2146233082
```

I know it has something to do with memory allocation, but I have no idea how to avoid this error. I have tried using Debug Diagnostics Tool 1.2, but even then I am not sure what to be looking for.

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

Public Class NetworkInfo

Dim CurrentDomain As AppDomain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain

'import the NetServerEnum function from the netapi32.dll 
Private Declare Unicode Function NetServerEnum Lib "netapi32" _
(ByVal Servername As IntPtr, _
ByVal Level As Integer, _
ByRef bufptr As IntPtr, _
ByVal PrefMaxLen As Integer, _
ByRef entriesread As Integer, _
ByRef TotalEntries As Integer, _
ByVal serverType As Integer, _
ByVal Domain As IntPtr, _
ByVal ResumeHandle As IntPtr) As Integer

'import the NetApiBufferFree function from the netapi32.dll
Private Declare Unicode Function NetApiBufferFree Lib "netapi32.dll" _
(ByRef buffer As IntPtr) As UInteger

Public Structure _SERVER_INFO_100
    Friend sv100_platform_id As Integer
    <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)> _
    Friend sv100_name As String
End Structure

Public Function GetNetworkComputers() As ArrayList

    Dim networkComputers As New ArrayList()
    Const MAX_PREFERRED_LENGTH As Integer = -1
    Dim SV_TYPE_WORKSTATION As Integer = 1
    Dim SV_TYPE_SERVER As Integer = 2
    Dim buffer As IntPtr = IntPtr.Zero
    Dim tmpBuffer As IntPtr = IntPtr.Zero
    Dim entriesRead As Integer = 0
    Dim totalEntries As Integer = 0
    Dim resHandle As Integer = 0


    Dim sizeofINFO As Integer = Marshal.SizeOf(GetType(_SERVER_INFO_100))

    Try
        Dim ret As Integer = NetServerEnum(Nothing, 100, buffer, MAX_PREFERRED_LENGTH,          entriesRead, totalEntries, _
                                           SV_TYPE_WORKSTATION Or SV_TYPE_SERVER, Nothing, resHandle)

        If ret = 0 Then
            For i As Integer = 0 To totalEntries
                tmpBuffer = New IntPtr(CType(buffer, Long) + (i * sizeofINFO))

                Dim svrInfo As _SERVER_INFO_100 = DirectCast(Marshal.PtrToStructure(tmpBuffer, _
                                                    GetType(_SERVER_INFO_100)), _SERVER_INFO_100)

                networkComputers.Add(svrInfo.sv100_name)

            Next
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        Console.WriteLine("Error getting network computers.")
    Finally
        NetApiBufferFree(buffer)
    End Try

    Return networkComputers
End Function

End Class
```

Comment: The sv100_name field must be an IntPtr so the marshaller doesn't try to release it.  Use Marshal.PtrToStringUni() to obtain the string.

Comment: Wow! That definitely fixed my error issue! Thank you so much! It's not a huge deal, but now sometimes it doesn't get any of the pc names. But then if I close the app and restart, they will show up. If I output to the console, it really doesn't retrieve any names on the first run, but always on the second.